# how to make drop-down list dependent using json?

Tags: angularjs, json

Im trying to create a dependent drop-down list box  using json.For example: if the car brand selected is "bmw" then the car model drop-down must display only "suv" from the list and other two options shouldn't be displayed.Likewise for "Mercedes" it should display only "suv" and "coupe" in the car model. And also please explain what is the use of json? also how it effect the code.

my.html

```
   Car Brand:
        <select name="carname" ng-model="userSelect" required>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
             <span ng-show="valdate.carname.$error.required">Car name</span>
            <option ng-repeat="ManufactureBrand in a" ng-bind="ManufactureBrand" >
                {{ManufactureBrand}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/> Car Model:
        <select name="carmodel" ng-model="selectCar" required>
              <option value="">--Select--</option>
              <span ng-show="valdate.carmodel.$error.required">Car name</span>
              <option ng-repeat="CarName in b" ng-bind="CarName">
                {{CarName}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br/>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="checkselection()" ng-disabled="valdate.carname.$invalid && valdate.carmodel.$invalid">
```

script.js

```
       app.factory('Brandtest', function () {
        var brand = {};
        brand.sample = ['Bmw', 'Mercedes', 'Honda'];
        brand.car = ['Suv', 'Sedan', 'Cope'];

        {
            return brand;
        }
    });

app.controller('selectDropdown', ['$scope', 'Brandtest', function ($scope, Brandtest) {
    $scope.a = Brandtest.sample;
    $scope.b = Brandtest.car;

    $scope.list=[];
    $scope.carlist=[];


    $scope.checkselection = function () {

        if ($scope.userSelect != "" && $scope.userSelect != undefined &&
            $scope.selectCar != "" && $scope.selectCar != undefined )
           {

           $scope.list.push($scope.userSelect);
           $scope.carlist.push($scope.selectCar);

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is pattern your following while rendering the dropdown with dependency.

Comment: The first drop down i.e car brand should display the car brand name . On selecting the specific car brand it should display only the car name related to that car brand in the next drop down. @StarkButtowski

Comment: What is valdate and Where if your form tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8uKhkeYTuq5AnGCqqlFH?p=preview)

You have to modified you code as below

**your factory should be like this**

```
app.factory('Brandtest', function () {
    var brand = {};
    brand.sample =[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "carName": "BMW"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "carName": "Mercedes"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "carName": "Honda"
        }
    ];
    brand.car =[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "carType": "Suv",
            "parentId": 0
        },

        {
            "id": 1,
            "carType": "Sedan",
            "parentId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "carType": "Cope",
            "parentId": 2
        }
    ];

    {
        return brand;
    }

});
```

**In your HTML modify the code like below**

```
<body ng-controller="selectDropdown">
 Car Brand:
        <select name="carname" ng-model="userSelect" ng-options="p.carName for p in a" required>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
             <span ng-show="valdate.carname.$error.required">Car name</span>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/> Car Model:
        <select name="carmodel" ng-model="selectCar" ng-options="c.carType for c in b | filter:{parentId: userSelect.id}" required>
              <option value="">--Select--</option>
              <span ng-show="valdate.carmodel.$error.required">Car name</span>
        </select>
        <br/>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="checkselection()" ng-disabled="valdate.carname.$invalid && valdate.carmodel.$invalid">
      <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Car Name</th>
                  <th>Car Model</th></tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat="carz in list track by $index">
                  <td>{{carz.carName}}</td>
                <td>{{carlist[$index].carType}}</td>
                </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain some co-relation between the 2 dropdowns. Better would be to have a single json object and use ng-options for populating the second dropdown based on value selected in first dropdown. Run the demo program below and you will get the point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>Select a car:</h1>
<select ng-model="x" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars"></select>
<h1 ng-if="x">Category: </h1>
<select ng-if="x" ng-model="y" ng-options="y for y in x"></select>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.cars = {
    "car01" : ["Ford", "BMW", "NISSAN"],
    "car02" : ["Fiat", "Infinity"],
    "car03" : ["Volvo", "Toyota"]
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add factory services also or it is not possible to use factory service ? @Vishal Gulati

Comment: for what do you want to add factory services?

Comment: It was an assigment given in my university to use factory and json in dependant drop-down box. So just want to know is it possible. @Vishal Gulati

Comment: yes you can. you can make a factory service to get the json using $http.

Comment: can you explain it. @Vishal Gulati

Comment: please explore yourself. Its not the portal to learn topics one after other. factory will be dependent on other angular concepts